# Test Multiple Server for login (WIndows 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, scripting, remote-desktop, rdp, batch-file

I currently run a PING sanity check test (batch file with result file) on over 80 servers in 4 environment.

But, even if we "ping" ok 100% of the servers, it doesn't mean that the machine are working properly. We had a couple of instances where a server was in a reboot limbo, but was pinging OK.

**My question is:**

First, I would create a Windows Test Account, or use my own admin account (ie: domain/user.test + password).

Is there a way for me to, lets say in the PRE-PROD environment, to log in on a machine, and from there, run a script of some sort, that would "test" and log in/log out of the 36 machines we have in PRE-PROD??? Also, maybe create and output file with results, like connected/logged out - OK....

Something like this?! I have scripting knowledge and created the ping test files, but really google out the web, and didn't find anything on this subject, so I need your help please!!

Comment: Wouldn't using Remote Desktop Services Manager work?  Simply add all the servers in and you can visually look down the list to see which server is "up" or "down"?  Of course this assumes remote admin is available.  But even if you did it from one of the servers in each environment, that would only be 4 places to check versus 80.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - a proper monitoring solution will test services for correct operation and response time. Login via RDP could be one of those services. If you're just using ping, all you're checking is ICMP ECHO.

If you don't have a proper monitoring product or solution, now you know some of the criteria to look for. You can certainly cobble up something on your own, but why reinvent the wheel? If you have 80 servers, you should be monitoring them properly. The people who write good software have hopefully already thought of the things you haven't thought of yet.

/edit per your response:
Rather than do it right, you want to do it homebrew? There is no easy way to login programatically via RDP using Windows native tools that I have found, on my own or via some Google searches. You can test if TCP 3389 is open of course, but that won't tell you if a sample user can login and get a desktop.

As long as you're willing to manually initiate the RDP sessions (using something like Terminals from Codeplex which will let you "connect to all", so that's only one click), then you could use a test account that has a specified login script that will run whatever you need it to.

Comment: I completely agree with what you say! And I know monitoring software already exists, but I wanted to try and find a way to monitor this via some sort of script, instead of installing some sort of software, as our monitoring team already does.

This solution is for 'department' based monitoring, and only to validate on my end, instead of engaging the monitoring people...

Comment: Edited my response.

Comment: So is there a way to easily do this with powershell or a kind of script ?

Comment: read what I wrote please : "There is no easy way to login programatically via RDP using Windows native tools that I have found, on my own or via some Google searches."

Comment: If you find one, then you've got your answer - please post it, you're certainly allowed to answer your own questions here, especially if you find something useful for others, which this would be.